# Whats wrong to install Grub?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I'm  trying to install ubuntu in my computer from pen drive. I can use ubuntu live from pen drive but whenever I try to install to my dard-drive I face some problems. I'm attaching two pictures where I'm getting wrong.

[image]
[image]

I don't know how to fix this. Could you give me some  details instructions?

I tried other version of Ubuntu  and fedora but it didn't work.

UPDATE:

In previous I was used to use Windows 7. The pc went slow so I decided to use Ubuntu. There was only  one drive c where I had the whole hard drive memory. As long as I understand that I have to make partition for  installing the ubuntu. I'm using  pendrive to  install the ubuntu. The proportion of my  hard rive is below: 
[image]

Comment: Is your drive sda setup in a RAID array? I'm curious.

Comment: Did you create a /boot partition ? efi ? We need more details of your install.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: @logan Yes I think so. Can't I install in that?

Comment: I think I didn't create a boot partition. @bodhi.zahen

Comment: Do you have a UEFI Bios? If so you should have a small **fat** partition (about 500 mb good enough) at the beginning of your disk to store boot files like GRUB. Did the setup automatically partition your disk in the way you show?